# How to wash without running water

Tags: cleaning, personal-care, bathroom, water, efficiency

I normally have running water from the City - today, the water main broke, meaning I have no running water for the foreseeable next couple of days - I am looking for lifehacks regarding how to clean oneself without using too much water, and preferably without any special equipment.

to clarify by "clean oneself", I am looking for a way to clean the skin (i.e. replacement for soap + water), hair (replacement for shampoo + water), and shave (without water).

Related Question [What should I do without hot water in the shower?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/301/what-should-i-do-without-hot-water-in-the-shower)

Comment: Do you want to stay at home? And you can't do a wipe-clean like astronauts?

Comment: @J. Musser staying at home is preferred, and I don't have any of the special no-water soap that astronauts use, so I don't think I can do that.. (But I may end up going to buy some)

Comment: Use baby wipes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of "waterless" skin cleansers, such as *Cetaphil*, *CVS Gentle Skin Cleanser* and *Family Dollar Gentle skin Cleanser* that are more gentle on the skin than soap and water. J.Musser's suggestion of baby wipes is equally valid.